# neo4j uni directional shortest path

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph with multiple nodes and edges that have a relation of (links_to) between them. Nodes represent web pages and edges a hyperlink. Pages have many links, inclusive reciprocal links.

**Problem:**

When I run the shortest path between A and C I'm getting a path that contains an invalid direction. Shortest path A-C

Instead of A->B->C I'm getting A<-B->C.

**How can I get the shortest path in the right direction?**

This is my query:

```
MATCH (home { Label:'/' }),(paris { Label:'/paris/2012/intervenants.php' }), 
p = shortestPath((home)-[:links_to]-(paris))
RETURN p
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHTQ3.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `*` (for many relationships between nodes) and direction:

> MATCH (home { Label:'/' }), (paris {
>   Label:'/paris/2012/intervenants.php' }),
>   p =
>   shortestPath((home)-[:links_to*]->(paris))
>   RETURN p

The good example of cypher query is in [link](http://neo4j.com/blog/finding-the-shortest-path-through-the-park/).

Comment: I've tried can't get it to work! I created a simpler graph.

# Node: /A # Section:none
# Node: /B # Section:none
# Node: /C # Section:none
# Node: /D # Section:none
#1  /A > /B
#2  /B > /A
#3  /B > /C
#4  /C > /D
#5  /D > /C
#6  /D > /A

even this MATCH p=({ Label:'/A' })-[:links_to]->({ Label:'/B' }) RETURN p gives me both directions. 

Any tip?

Comment: The visual is showing all the edges on a node, thats what's confusing. If I do the same query on the data browser it seems to be correct. Any way to do it visually?

Comment: I am afraid of visualisation of the browser (the default of Neo4j) show all relationships between of returned nodes everytime.

Comment: I tried doing it on the data browser and it is still the same invalid data. How can I know the shortest path on a given direction? What should I use?

Comment: You should show the result. If you use `-->` it has to return path with this direction only (in the Rows window of Neo4j browser).